# what happens here: typedef int (*ptr) (void) in .h file C

Tags: c, function-pointers, declaration, typedef, implicit-conversion

I have a piece of C code and don't understand what happens here:

```
typedef int (*ptr) (void *ptr2, const char *name);
```

What I do understand is the typedef int (*ptr) part, but what happens in the second()? I've seen some questions where it was the other way around: `typedef void (*ptr) (int)`, is this similar or different (and how)? I'm not the best at C, so I thought maybe *ptr now points to a function where *ptr2 and *name are declared or *ptr now points to *ptr2 and *name?

It would be great if someone could explain this to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It could have been just `typedef int (*ptr) (void *, const char *);`. The names of the parameters are only for documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have for example a function declaration like

```
int f( void *ptr2, const char *name );
```

(as it is seen the function type is `int( void *, const char * )`) then a pointer to the function will look like

```
int ( *pf )( void *, const char * ) = f;
```

and the type of the pointer `pf` is `int ( * )( void *, const char * )`. That is the pointer `pf` now contains the address of the function `f`.

To introduce an alias for this function pointer type you can write

```
typedef int (*ptr) (void *ptr2, const char *name);
```

In this case the above declaration of the pointer `pf` will look like

```
ptr pf = f;
```

that is the declaration of the pointer is simplified.

Pay attention to that the function name used as an initializer of the pointer is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function. That is you could write

```
ptr pf = &f;
```

but due to the implicit conversion it is enough to write

```
ptr pf = f;
```